# Spark 2 to Spark 1.6

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to convert following code to run on the spark 1.6 but, on which I am facing certain issues. while converting the sparksession to context

```
 object TestData {
  def makeIntegerDf(spark: SparkSession, numbers: Seq[Int]): DataFrame =
    spark.createDataFrame(
      spark.sparkContext.makeRDD(numbers.map(Row(_))),
      StructType(List(StructField("column", IntegerType, nullable = false)))
    )

}
```

How Do I convert it to make it run on spark 1.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SparkSession` is supported from *spark 2.0* on-wards only. So if you want to use *spark 1.6* then you would need to create `SparkContext` and `sqlContext` in driver class and pass them to the function.

so you can create

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("simple")
val sparkContext = new SparkContext(conf)
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sparkContext)
```

and then call the function as

```
val callFunction = makeIntegerDf(sparkContext, sqlContext, numbers)
```

And your function should be as

```
def makeIntegerDf(sparkContext: SparkContext, sqlContext: SQLContext, numbers: Seq[Int]): DataFrame =
    sqlContext.createDataFrame(
      sparkContext.makeRDD(numbers.map(Row(_))),
      StructType(List(StructField("column", IntegerType, nullable = false)))
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

The only main difference here is the use of spark which is a spark session as opposed to spark context.

So you would do something like this:

```
object TestData {
  def makeIntegerDf(sc: SparkContext, sqlContext: SQLContext, numbers: Seq[Int]): DataFrame =
    sqlContext.createDataFrame(
      sc.makeRDD(numbers.map(Row(_))),
      StructType(List(StructField("column", IntegerType, nullable = false)))
    )
}
```

Of course you would need to create a spark context instead of spark session in order to provide it to the function.

Comment: I think there is need of sqlContext too. :) don't you think so?

Comment: @Assaf  I think `spark.createDataFrame`  should be `sc.createDataFrame` , I tried but not its not resolving . aslo does it have createDataFrame or rdd.toDf ?

Comment: @Freeman You are correct, I missed that one. I updated the answer, you need to use sqlContext.

Comment: @Freeman You can use toDF if you import sqlContext.implicits._ You should even be able to do numbers.toDF("column")